# Jetpack share buttons don't show on home page with custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, jetpack

I use Jetpack share buttons with a custom theme (Tyler theme from ShowThemes). The share buttons appears on all pages except the home page. If I set the homepage to static (theme options) the share buttons work. But I need to put the homepage in the "dynamic mode" in order to display content based on the theme settings, and in this mode the buttons doesn't work.

Since I am not familiar with WP and filters, what should I do in order to display the share butons on this page ?

I tried do add  the following code in the index.php (this is the home page) but it does not work :

```
<?php echo sharing_display() ?>
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this option "show buttons on" on this page: /wp-admin/options-general.php?page=sharing#sharing-buttons
and tick the checkbox "homepage, archives and search results"?
Probably that's what you are looking for